# Background con varias imagenes en CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

estoy tratando de hacer una section de una página que tiene como fondo un video, y por encima del video, una imagen en png.

No logro dar con la forma correcta de hacerlo.

Este es el código:

```css
#background-video {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1000;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.background-video-image {
  max-height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -999;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url('../images/backgrounds/video-bckg.png');
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="">
  <div class="background-video-image">

  </div>
  <video autoplay muted loop id="background-video">
                <source src="assets/videos/corto.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>


</section>
```

Esto es todo lo que tengo por ahora, pero no funciona como debería funcionar. Tanto el video como la imagen deben cubrir el 100% del width, y respecto al height, también en un 100% de lo que se estaría viendo en pantalla.

Luego la idea es aplicar otras imágenes, textos y botones a este fondo, pero eso es para otra ocasión.

Por el memento, logro que el video logre ocupar el 100% del ancho y el alto, pero al aplicar la imagen, esta no llega a cubrir a todo el video, me queda una parte abajo del video sin cubrir.

***Aclaraciones:***

• Estoy usando bootstrap 4, pero creo que no hay clases de bootstrap que esté utilizando en esta parte del código.

• Esta es otra parte del css que estoy usando:

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:  0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el atributo poster; el el fondo del video cuando lo cargas o como tu quieres:

```html
<video controls="" poster="https://cutt.ly/-s" src="video.mp4"></video>
```

Y luego puedes añadir tus estilos para que ocupe toda la pantalla, sin modificar la imagen porque es el fondo del video.

Comment: Esto funciona, aunque no sé si el OP quiera que la imagen se conserve a medida que el video se reproduce.

Comment: Voy a hacerlo mejor

Comment: <img class="un" src="https://intranet.virgenmedallamilagrosa.com/assets/images/insignia.png">
<video class="un" style="display:block" controls="">
<style>
.un{width:100%}
</style>